# ERROR: iot_tls_connect L#232 failed ! mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x2700

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

At the moment my study group and I are working on a project. In an attempt to use AWS IoT Core we are trying to use aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-c. We have created a Thing, created a certificate and downloaded the private key, public (for no reason) key, the certificate and downloaded a root Ca. We have placed these keys and certificates in the certs folder. 
The thing also has a policy which allows everything currently. We just want a simple connection working before securing anything.

We hope to simply connect using the subscribe_publish_sample in the SDK before proceeding to use the SDK for our own purposes.

We have edited the aws_iot_config.h file to match the naming of the certificates, keys and hostname of our shadow.

So far we haven't been able to find a specific post on any forums about the -0x2700 error code.

The output:

```
AWS IoT SDK Version 3.0.1-

DEBUG:   main L#159 rootCA /Users/Andy/Documents/Arduino/libraries/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample/../../../certs/rootCa.pem
DEBUG:   main L#160 clientCRT /Users/Andy/Documents/Arduino/libraries/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample/../../../certs/2386622fde-certificate.pem.crt
DEBUG:   main L#161 clientKey /Users/Andy/Documents/Arduino/libraries/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/samples/linux/subscribe_publish_sample/../../../certs/2386622fde-private.pem.key
Connecting...
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#130 
  . Seeding the random number generator...
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#138   . Loading the CA root certificate ...
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#144  ok (0 skipped)

DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#146   . Loading the client cert. and key...
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#159  ok

DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#161   . Connecting to xxxxxxxxx-xxx.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/8883...
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#180  ok

DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#182   . Setting up the SSL/TLS structure...
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#223 

SSL state connect : 0 
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#226  ok

DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#228 

SSL state connect : 0 
DEBUG:   iot_tls_connect L#229   . Performing the SSL/TLS handshake...
DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#49 
Verify requested for (Depth 3):

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#51 cert. version     : 3
serial number     : A7:0E:4A:4C:34:82:B7:7F
issuer name       : C=US, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
subject name      : C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
issued  on        : 2009-09-02 00:00:00
expires on        : 2034-06-28 17:39:16
signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
RSA key size      : 2048 bits
basic constraints : CA=true
key usage         : Digital Signature, Key Cert Sign, CRL Sign

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#56 cert. version     : 3
serial number     : A7:0E:4A:4C:34:82:B7:7F
issuer name       : C=US, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
subject name      : C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
issued  on        : 2009-09-02 00:00:00
expires on        : 2034-06-28 17:39:16
signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
RSA key size      : 2048 bits
basic constraints : CA=true
key usage         : Digital Signature, Key Cert Sign, CRL Sign

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#57 cert. version     : 3
serial number     : A7:0E:4A:4C:34:82:B7:7F
issuer name       : C=US, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., OU=Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
subject name      : C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
issued  on        : 2009-09-02 00:00:00
expires on        : 2034-06-28 17:39:16
signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
RSA key size      : 2048 bits
basic constraints : CA=true
key usage         : Digital Signature, Key Cert Sign, CRL Sign


DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#49 
Verify requested for (Depth 2):

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#51 cert. version     : 3
serial number     : 06:7F:94:4A:2A:27:CD:F3:FA:C2:AE:2B:01:F9:08:EE:B9:C4:C6
issuer name       : C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=Starfield Technologies, Inc., CN=Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
subject name      : C=US, O=Amazon, CN=Amazon Root CA 1
issued  on        : 2015-05-25 12:00:00
expires on        : 2037-12-31 01:00:00
signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
RSA key size      : 2048 bits
basic constraints : CA=true
key usage         : Digital Signature, Key Cert Sign, CRL Sign

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#54   This certificate has no flags

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#49 
Verify requested for (Depth 1):

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#51 cert. version     : 3
serial number     : 06:7F:94:57:85:87:E8:AC:77:DE:B2:53:32:5B:BC:99:8B:56:0D
issuer name       : C=US, O=Amazon, CN=Amazon Root CA 1
subject name      : C=US, O=Amazon, OU=Server CA 1B, CN=Amazon
issued  on        : 2015-10-22 00:00:00
expires on        : 2025-10-19 00:00:00
signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
RSA key size      : 2048 bits
basic constraints : CA=true, max_pathlen=0
key usage         : Digital Signature, Key Cert Sign, CRL Sign

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#54   This certificate has no flags

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#49 
Verify requested for (Depth 0):

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#51 cert. version     : 3
serial number     : 06:C9:C7:B7:84:F0:8F:8B:34:87:5D:DD:81:FF:E4:F0
issuer name       : C=US, O=Amazon, OU=Server CA 1B, CN=Amazon
subject name      : CN=*.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
issued  on        : 2018-08-02 00:00:00
expires on        : 2019-08-02 12:00:00
signed using      : RSA with SHA-256
RSA key size      : 2048 bits
basic constraints : CA=false
subject alt name  : iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com, *.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
key usage         : Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
ext key usage     : TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication

DEBUG:   _iot_tls_verify_cert L#54   This certificate has no flags

ERROR: iot_tls_connect L#232  failed
  ! mbedtls_ssl_handshake returned -0x2700

ERROR: iot_tls_connect L#239     Unable to verify the server's certificate. Either it is invalid,
    or you didn't set ca_file or ca_path to an appropriate value.
    Alternatively, you may want to use auth_mode=optional for testing purposes.

ERROR: main L#190 Error(-4) connecting to xxxxxxxxx-xxxx.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:8883
```

We have tried replacing all certificates, keys, things, policies etc. so we must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A common problem in that case is that with me greengrass group doesn't have the proper subscription.

AWS IoT Core is used over MQTT so make share your thing has the proper topics enabled in:

```
The greengrass group subscriptions
The thing's certificate.
```

Victor Nizeyimana

Comment: We haven't touched greengrass at all so we didn't expect any need for adding groru subscriptions. Are you sure this is necessary?